# catch multiple exception does not work

Tags: python

I tried to use try except to catch multiple exception. however I still cannot catch both expection and error is print out as following. any help is appreciate

```
def try_expection(self:
    try:
        el = self.element.test_function()
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        el = self.driver.test_function()

Error:
def try_expection(self):
    try:
```

> ```
>       el = self.element.test_function()
> ```
>
> E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test_function'

Comment: Did you check that `self.driver` is defined? The problem doesn't seem to be with the multiple `except` blocks

Comment: yes, i tried to use pycharm debug line by line and it is able to catch it..so i am stuck

Comment: Try to print `self.driver` before you call `self.driver.test_function()` to see if it exists...

Comment: yes, it is there

Comment: `self.driver`exists but this object (None) does not have an attribute or mathod named `test_function`.

Comment: but the error i for self.element.test_function.. that means all attributeError or TypeError should be catched then executing self.driver line